# GCS Notifications not shown in Pub/Sub Topic message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-storage

We have a GCS bucket named 'testfiles' and Pub/Sub topic 'testtopic' with a subscription 'testsubscription'. We have created a notification configuration to receive notifications on the Pub/Sub topic for any event happening on the GCS bucket. When we run the following command to list the notifications on the bucket,

```
gcloud storage buckets notifications list gs://testfiles
```

we see the below output,

```
{
  "kind": "storage#notification",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/testfiles/notificationConfigs/28",
  "id": "28",
  "topic": "//pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/test-project/topics/testtopic",
  "etag": "28",
  "payload_format": "JSON_API_V1"
}
```

Also, we have provided the Cloud Storage Service account the Pub/Sub Publisher role.

Despite these settings, when we upload a file to the bucket 'testfiles', we do not see any JSON messages in the above mentioned topic/subscription (testtopic/testsubscription).

We tried to follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)

Please advise, if there is something we are missing.

Comment: You pulled the message from the GCP `PubSub` console and with a command line ?

Comment: No I pulled the message through a standalone Java application code

Answer (score 0):

The console (GCP console, console.cloud.google.com) was not displaying the Pub/Sub messages. However, when we connect to Pub/Sub topic's subscription through a listener code, it was able to receive the JSON messages without any issues.